# inheritance and polymorphism conflict

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

if a `Fruit` class is superClass and `Apple` and `Orange` are subclasses of Fruit,
 and `GoldenDelicious` and `Macintosh` are sub classes of `Apple`.

Assume that the following declaration is given:

```
Fruit fruit = new GoldenDelicious();
Orange orange = new Orange();
```

Answer this question with explain

Suppose the method `makeAppleCider` is defined in the `Apple` class. Can
`fruit` invoke this method? Can orange invoke this method???

My answer is : Can
fruit invoke this method? No beacuse there aren't explicit cast , must do explicit cast of
                          fruit instance to enable invoke the method defined in Apple                                  class. dose this answer is true ????

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a homework assignment. Is it?

Comment: @Aidanc - there is a suggested solution at the end of the question in the last paragraph.

Comment: no, i am studying java from a introduction to java book and i solve the questions after each chapter.
So, i want to know the true answer, because i had conflict in object casting and polymorphism.
It didn't a homework.
I am studying it self study

Comment: @MahmoudEmam you are best off stating that in your question in the future. It just matters for the way questions are answered.

Comment: introduction to java programming book had answers on it review questions, the answer is yes and i can't understand it, so i asked the question here to ensure about the concept of inheritance and Polymorphism

Comment: @MahmoudEmam I'm not saying you did anything wrong in asking the question here, I just believe it would have been helpful to give that context, with a sentence along the lines of "I am studying java from a introduction to java book and came across this question and didn't understand the answer given in the book" in your qeustion.

Answer (score 1):

This dives into the static and dynamic types of a variable.

```
Fruit fruit;
```

This line declares a variable `fruit` with static type `Fruit`. This type will never change (it's static after all) and is what you will usually be using.

```
fruit = new GoldenDelicious();
```

This line is one that assigns a value that is a `GoldenDelicious` to that variable. The dynamic type of the variable does change to reflect this change. After all, the variable actually contains a `GoldenDelicious` now. The dynamic type is something you usually won't be working with, but it is what is used when you use the (evil) `instanceof` (and it makes sure that overwritten function are called in the right place).

Now, you want to do this:

```
fruit.makeAppleCider();
```

This will not work. Of fruit, we basically only know the static type, and the static type `Fruit` knows nothing of that method. (However, behind the scenes, if `GoldenDelicious` and `Macintosh` implement the function in different ways, the dynamic type will make sure the right version is called.)

As you mentioned in your answer, explicit casts could be used to change the static type of what you are working with, and as such you could make it work that way. It is better not to do that, though, as casts should be avoided and aren't "proper OOP".

In conclusion, yes, your answer was correct.

(Yes, my description is a bit technical. I hope you'll forgive me for that...)

Answer (score 0):

A `Fruit` has no "knowledge" of the `makeAppleCider` method. `makeAppleCider` is defined in a subclass and is not a member of `Fruit`. A class only has access to the methods it or one of its parents defines. Given a class of a certain type, you have to trace back up the class hierarchy to see what methods you can access. You can think of the type of your variable as the starting place for the walk back up the class hierarchy.

If there is a method you want all of your classes to have access to, put it in the root of the hierarchy. Obviously, the logic of using the method should make sense or people who use your code will be confused.

Answer (score 0):

The other option, of course, is to use an "interface" -- a sort of poor-man's multiple inheritance (but far easier to understand and implement than full-out multiple inheritance).

You could, eg, have an interface sorta like (not syntax checked):

```
public interface CiderFruit {
    public void makeCider();
}
```

Then Apple could implement the interface:

```
public class Apple extends Fruit implements CiderFruit {
    ....
    public void makeCider() {
        doStuff();
    }
    ....
}
```

If you then had a Quince class it could implement the same interface and one could take either an Apple or a Quince, cast it to CiderFruit (if unsure whether it's Apple or Quince), and invoke `makeCider()`.  (One could also invoke directly with a reference typed as Apple or Quince.)